# Asymptotic property for coupon collector's problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In the classic coupon collector's problem, we let $T_N$ be the time it takes for the collector to collect all of the coupons in the collection. It is easy to see that, in the case where each of the coupons is obtained with probability $\frac1N$ at each step, $T_N$ is a sum of independent geometric random variables which yields $\mathbb E[T_N]=NH_N$ and in turn $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mathbb E[T_N]}{N\log N}=1$. Knowing this, how can one show that :
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb P(T_N-N\log N\le Nx)=e^{-e^{-x}},\quad x\in\mathbb R$$?

I tried multiple different approaches, but nothing has worked thus far. Markov's inequality is a bit useless (as an attempt to exhibit an expectation), and attempting to write $T_N=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(T_{k+1}-T_k)$ to get a sum of independent random variables whose laws we know doesn't seem to yield any interesting result either. I feel like it should be possible to express the probability in the left-hand side as $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^ke^{-kx}}{k!}$ which would give the result by letting $N\rightarrow\infty$ but I don't know how to prove this (nor if it's true for that matter). Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I note $\mathbb{P}(T_N \leq x) = S(x,N) N!\, N^{-N}$ where $S(x,N)$ is a Stirling number of the second kind.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Extensions_and_generalizations), a proof is given in _Probability and Computing: Randomized Algorithms and Probabilistic Analysis_ by Mitzenmacher and Upfal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer is based on the proof of this theorem given in *Probability and Computing: Randomized Algorithms and Probabilistic Analysis*, by Mitzenmacher and Upfal. The method is via Poisson approximation.

The event $\{T_n\le n\log n+nx\}$ is equivalent to the following. Let $$m=n\log n+nx.$$ We throw $m$ balls independently and uniformly likely into $n$ bins, and ask the probability that all bins are occupied. Each bin is a coupon, and throwing a ball into a bin means you collect that coupon.

Consider a different experiment. Let $Z_1,\dots,Z_n$ be a list of independent Poisson random variables, each with mean $\log n+x=m/n$. We stipulate that the $i^\text{th}$ bin receives $Z_i$ balls, and let $E$ be the event that all of the $Z_i$ are nonzero. Since the $Z_i$ are independent (unlike for the balls-and-bins problem), we can easily compute
$$
P(E)=(1-e^{-x-\ln n})^n=(1-e^{-x}/n)^n\to e^{-e^{-x}}\qquad \text{as }n\to\infty.
$$
This is answer we want. We just need to show that the probability for the Poisson experiment is the same as for the balls-in-bins experiment, in the limit.

The key idea is this. Let $Z=Z_1+\dots+Z_n$. Note that $P(E\mid Z=m)$ is exactly equal to the probability that every bin is occupied when $m$ balls are thrown in $n$ bins (see Theorem 5.6 in *Probability and Computing*). Therefore, we proceed in two steps.

1. Show that $Z$ is tightly concentrated around its mean, in the sense that $$P(|Z-m|> \sqrt{2m\log m})=o(1)\text{ as }n\to\infty$$Since $Z$ is itself Poisson distributed with mean $m$, this is a standard fact about Poisson variables. You can prove this using the Chernoff bound.
2. Show that, no matter where $Z$ lands in the interval $[m-\sqrt{2m\log n},m+\sqrt{2m\log n}]$, the conditional probability $P(E\mid Z)$ is approximately the same. Therefore, when $Z$ is in this interval, we can approximate $P(E\mid Z)$ by $P(E\mid Z=m)$.

Assuming we have completed these two steps, we conclude as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
e^{-e^{-x}}=P(E)
&=P(E\mid |Z-m|\le \sqrt{2m \log m})P(|Z-m|\le \sqrt{2m \log m})
\\
&\quad+P(E\mid |Z-m|> \sqrt{2m \log m})P(|Z-m|> \sqrt{2m \log m})
\\
&=\Big(P(E\mid Z=m)-o(1)\Big)\cdot (1-o(1))
\\&\quad +P(E\mid |Z-m|> \sqrt{2m \log m})\cdot o(1)
\\&= P(E\mid Z=m)+o(1)
\\&= P(T_n\le n\log n + nx)+o(1).
\end{align}
$$

Here is the idea for how to complete step $2$. Note that the function $P(E\mid Z=r)$ is an increasing function of $r$; when you throw more balls, the probability that all bins are occupied increases. Therefore, for any $r$ in the interval $[m-\sqrt{2m\log m},m+\sqrt{2m \log m}]$, the error between $P(E\mid Z=r)$ and $P(E\mid Z=m)$ is at most
$$
P(E\mid Z=m+\sqrt{2m \log m})-P(E\mid Z=m-\sqrt{2m\log m})
$$
This is the difference between the probability that all $n$ bins are occupied when $m+\sqrt{2m \log m}$ balls are thrown, versus when $m-\sqrt{2m \log m}$ balls are thrown. This difference is equal to the probability of the following experiment; we first throw $m-\sqrt{2m \log m}$ balls into $n$ bins, after which there is still some empty bin, but throwing an additional $2\sqrt{2m \log m}$ balls causes all bins to be full. However, the probability that one of the $2\sqrt{2m \log m}$ thrown balls will land in any particular bin is at most $(2\sqrt{2m \log m})/n=o(1)$ by the union bound, so the difference is $o(1)$ as well.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a heuristic argument (not a proof). $e^{-e^{-x}}$ describes a [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution); these occur as [extreme value distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution) describing the asymptotics of the maximum $\text{max}(X_1, \dots X_N)$ of $N$ iid samples from some distribution, suitably rescaled (by the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem)). So, is there an interpretation of what's going on in terms of maxima?

Consider the random variables $t_1, \dots t_N$ describing the time it takes for each individual coupon to be collected. Each $t_i$ is individually geometrically distributed with $p = \frac{1}{N}$, and $T_N = \text{max}(t_1, \dots t_N)$. Now, the $t_i$ are *not* independent; but heuristically, if we calculate as if they are, we obtain (if $N$ is large and $M$ is not too much larger than $N$)

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \mathbb{P}(T_N \le M) &\approx& \mathbb{P}(t_1 \le M)^N \\
 &\approx& \left( 1 - \left( 1 - \frac{1}{N} \right)^M \right)^N \\
 &\approx& \left( 1 - e^{-\frac{M}{N}} \right)^N. \end{eqnarray*} $$

(This last step corresponds to the Poisson approximation mentioned by Mike Earnest.) Substituting $M = N \log N + Nx$ now gives

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \mathbb{P}(T_N \le N \log N + Nx) &\approx& \left( 1 - e^{ - \log N - x } \right)^N \\
 &\approx& \left( 1 - \frac{e^{-x}}{N} \right)^N \end{eqnarray*}$$

which converges to $e^{-e^{-x}}$ as $N \to \infty$ as desired.

Again, this is a heuristic argument, and I don't know if it can be cleaned up into a proof, but at least it explains why one might conjecture a result like this. If I were looking for a proof I might try applying the [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) since the moment generating function is computable but it looks messy. Alternatively, as aschepler notes in the comments, $\mathbb{P}(T_N \le M)$ can be expressed in terms of Stirling numbers and one might be able to do something with one of their generating functions.